# Django on mod_wsgi syntaxError

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I installed Django 1.11.5 with Virtualenv on mod_wsgi.

python version is 2.7.13.

I get this error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26] mod_wsgi (pid=9606): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/memit/memit/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26] mod_wsgi (pid=9606): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/memit/memit/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]   File "/var/www/html/memit/memit/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]   File "/var/www/html/memit/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]   File "/var/www/html/memit/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]     from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]   File "/var/www/html/memit/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]                      ^
[Wed Sep 13 16:41:00 2017] [error] [client 5.125.70.26]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And My Apache virtual host is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName memit.ir
    ServerAlias www.memit.ir
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/memit

    WSGIDaemonProcess memit python-path=/var/www/html/memit:/var/www/html/memit/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup memit
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/memit/memit/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/html/memit>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong?

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using python 2.7? Set literals is not supported in python 2.6, but was backported from python 3 to python 2.7.

Comment: Check what version of Python mod_wsgi is actually compiled for. You cannot force mod_wsgi compiled for one version of Python to work with a virtual environment compiled for a newer Python version. The error indicates your mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, I'm sure. The result of excute `env/bin/python --version` is `Python 2.7.13`.

Comment: The line that causes the error is valid syntax in python 2.7, but would raise  a syntaxerror in python 2.6. @GrahamDumpleton's comment seems to explain what's wrong. mod_wsgi is not using env/bin/python, but instead python 2.6. It's very common to have several versions of python installed.

Comment: Yes, read the link. The mod_wsgi module doesn't use the command line program from the virtual environment. It is linked to the Python shared library and pointing it at a virtual environment for a different version doesn't change that.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thank you. I removed mod_wsgi and reinstall that by [this guide](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html). My problem is now solved.